# AS3commons zip with subdirectories

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zip

I've been using the as3commons zip library to package images for user download, and have found it very easy to use so far, but I need the files to be organised in directories - after a day of trawling I can find nothing which indicates how one creates subdirectories in a zip file, everything I've found focuses on adding files to the root. Does anyone know how I'd go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as3commons does the subdirectories for you: just pass the full path to the file with the arguments. Here's an old (partial) sample of mine. It takes an folder and a zip file (:File) as an argument (here it's `tempDir:File`)

```
private var zip:Zip = new Zip();
private var zipFile:File = new File();
private var filesToCompress:int = 1;
private var filesCompressed:int = 0;


    /*** further on ***/

    /*** 
     * Waits until all files are compressed and then serializes the zip.
     * */

    public function fileAddedToZip():void{
        filesCompressed++;          
        if (filesToCompress == filesCompressed){

            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.openAsync(zipFile, FileMode.WRITE);

            zip.serialize(stream);                  
            stream.close();
            tempDir.deleteDirectoryAsync(true);         

        }
    }       


    /*** Adds file to zip but doesn't serialize the zip yet 
     * 
     * @param file current file 
     * @param zip save destination
     * @param path current folder nativepath
     * **/


    public function addFileToZip(file:File, zip:Zip, path:String=""):void{
        if(file.isDirectory){
            var directory:Array = file.getDirectoryListing();
            filesToCompress = filesToCompress + directory.length;

            for each (var f:File in directory){
                addFileToZip(f, zip, path + "/" + file.name);
            }
            fileAddedToZip();
        }else{

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.nativePath);
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);

            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void {

                var pathSplit:Array = file.nativePath.split(".tmp\\",2);
                var fileNamePath:String = pathSplit[1] as String;                   
                zip.addFile(fileNamePath, event.target.data);

                fileAddedToZip();

            });
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlLoader.load(request);


        }
    }
```